# Android responsive design qualifiers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Lately I have been really struggling to get my app look nice on every device. And I found out a lot of things I have been doing wrong (Using hardcoded sizes, using layouts wrong.. ) So I have fixed it and now I'm setting different qualifiers for different layouts. I'm using smallest width qualifier, but I can't figure out how many of different layouts should I make and what the best values for qualifiers are. I tried using 300,340,380,420,460,500 for smallest width, but my design still doesn't look clean on each device as I would like it to be. Anyone could give an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Using [sdp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) (scalable dp) and [ssp](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)(scalable sp) you can maintain the same UI structure on almost every device.

Comment: According to this website [link](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) you still need to create different layouts when using ssp and sdp, so I want to know what qualifiers to use for them. @Amirhosein

Comment: See: https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints

Comment: `ssp` and `sdp` works based on different predefined qualifiers (sw-300, sw-330, sw1080, ...) which in my opinion are enough to support different screens, despite the fact that these are not suggested breakpoints in material design.